# 0 Checking if TextBox.Text contains the string in the table. But it doesn't work? Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am making a script inside TextButton script that will check if the TextBox contains any of the word or string inside the table.

```
text = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild('TextBox')
label = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild('TextLabel')

a = {'test1','test2','test3'}

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
     if  string.match(text.Text, a) then
     label.Text = "The word "..text.Text.." was found in the table."
 else
     label.Text = "The word "..text.Text.." was not found in the table."
 end
 end)
```

But it gives an error ***string expected, got table.*** from line **7** which is refering to the line *if string.match....*

Is there any way to get all text in the table?

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, there's a lot to say about this.

## The error message

Yes.

No, seriously, the answer is yes. The error message is exactly right. `a` is a table value; you can clearly see that on the third line of code. `string.match` needs a string as its second argument, so it obviously crashes.

## Simple solution

use a `for` loop and check for each string in `a` separately.

```
found = false
for index, entry in ipairs(a) do
  if entry == text.Text then
    found = true
  end
end
if found then
... -- the rest of your code
```

## The *better** solution

In Lua, if we want to know if a single element is in a set, we usually take advantage of the fact that tables are implemented as hashmaps, meaning they are very fast when looking up keys.

For that to work, one first needs to change the way the table looks:

```
a = {["test1"] = true, ["test2"] = true, ["test3"] = true}
```

Then we can just index `a` with a string to find out if it is contained int eh set.

```
if a[text.Text] then ...
```

* In practice this is just as good as the first solution as long as you only have *a few* elements in your table. It only becomes relevant when you have a few hundred entries *or* your code needs to run absolutely as fast as possible.